# Show that any solutions exists to $x'' + x + x^3= 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that any solutions exists to $x'' + x + x^3= 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$

I don't know if $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is a typo or $x = x(t)$, but in any case i'm not sure how to show solutions exists for this second order ODE. Can anyone offer advice?

Comment: Uh...there is a solution $x \equiv0$. Perhaps some part of the question is cut off? Perhaps the problem wants you to prove that an IVP can be solvedfor any initial data.

Comment: yes there is another solution

Comment: I know $x=0$ works, but I was thinking the exercise wants more than the trivial solution

Comment: For other initial conditions, Picard-Lindelof easily gives local existence but for global existence you will need to do some estimation to ensure that there is no blowup in finite time.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: there are plenty of solutions (we may solve that ODE by using Jacobi functions, for instance), but the point is to show that $x\equiv 0$ is the only global solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ x''x'=-(x+x^3)x' $ implies
$$ x'^2 = C-2x^2-x^4 \tag{1}$$
but for any $C$ given by the initial conditions, the RHS of $(1)$ is negative as soon as $x$ is large enough, hence the associated solution "dies" before reaching that point. In particular, there are no global solutions unless $x'\equiv 0$.

Comment: Jack, thank you for your answer. I have a couple questions. I do not fully understand the reasoning behind there not existing a solution. Why does the RHS being negative mean the solution "dies" before reaching 'that point'. Is that point the initial condition point? Like $x(0) = 1$?

Comment: @callkmo: for sure, $x'^{\color{red}{2}}$ cannot equal, say, $-2$. The Cauchy-Lipschitz conditions hence give that a solution cannot be extended beyond some point. Anyway, $(1)$ is a separable ODE: $$\frac{x'}{\sqrt{C-2x^2-x^4}} = 1 $$ so you may explicitly write the solutions by inverting the integral $\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{C-2u^2-u^4}}$, that is an elliptic integral.

Comment: Jack, thank you (again) for the detailed reply. So the Cauchy-Lipschitz conditions end up telling us that there is no solution beyond some point (when $x' \equiv 0$). These solutions are explicitly found via the elliptic integral you wrote. I have heard elliptic integrals are difficult to solve.

Comment: @callkmo: you got me wrong. The Cauchy-Lipschitz conditions and the study of the convexity of solutions give us that $x\equiv 0$ is the only global solution. A Jacobi $\text{Sn}$ function is not a pleasant object to deal with, I agree, but if a solution is given by the inverse function of a bounded function, it cannot be global.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks a bunch. I've got a lot of googling to do :)